# Existence of composition series of infinite groups (especially the braid groups and the general linear group)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, infinite-groups, braid-groups

How can I argue that there are no composition series for the braid groups or the general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ ?
I have already learned that this is related to the infinite abelianization of these groups.
But it is not clear to me why I can conclude from an infinite abelianization that there is no composition series for these infinite groups.
I would be very happy if someone could explaint this to me.

Comment: As I think have said in a previous comment to the same question, this follows from the fact that an infinite abelian group cannot have a composition series, and that is because the only abelian simple groups are finite groups of prime order.

Comment: Oh yes thanks a lot! Is it possible to conclude this analogously for the groups $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, $SO(n)$ and $SU(n)$ ? \ The group $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is perfect, so if I want to determine the abelianization of the special linear group, I would receive the trivial group?

Comment: Yes it's trivial. ${\rm SL}(n,{\mathbb R})$ has finite centre of order $1$ or $2$, and the quotient by its centre is the simple group ${\rm PSL}(n,{\mathbb R})$, so it has a composition series. The other two are similar.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Why can I conclude from the quotient $SL(n,\mathbb{R})/\{+I,-I\}$ that a composition series exists? And how do I determine the composition series of  $SL(n,\mathbb{R}) $ in the end? The center of $SO(2)$ for example is trivial, because it is an abelian group, so the abelianization of SO(2) should be infinite and it is not possible that a finite composition series exists? The center of $SU(2)$ is a cyclic group of order 2 but how the abelianization looks like...I don't know. In case the abelianization is finite, how do I determine the composition series of that group?

Comment: You are asking too many new questions in a comment. I will just answer for $G = {\rm SL}(n,{\mathbb R})$. When $n$ is odd the centre is trivial, and $G$ is simple, so $1 <  G$ is a composition series. When $n$ is even, the centre is $Z = \{I,-I\}$, and $1 < Z< G$ is a composition series. In both of these examples the composition series is unique, but in general there could be more than one.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Okay, I'm sorry. That helps me a lot, thank you so much. I would still be interested to see how the composition series look for the group $SU(2)$. Could you help me out here, too?

Comment: $1 < \{I,-I\} < {\rm SU}(2)$ is a composition series for ${\rm SU}(2)$. Note that ${\rm SU}(2)/\{\pm I\}$ is isomorphic to the simple group ${\rm SO}(3)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ah, thanks a lot! Can you recommend a source for this context?  Is it correct to conclude that there doesn't exist a composition series for the group $SO(2)$ , since the group is abelian and the abelianization of that group is infinite (analogous to the group $GL(2,\mathbb{R}$ )?

Comment: You are just continuing to come up with an endless stream of new questions!